Typing in large markdown buffers is slow due to corfu and flyspell. How to address?
When I type in a large (1000+ lines, tens of thousands of words) Markdown buffer, the typing feels slow. My profiler reports this
Memory

Bytes       %     Function
14,151,043  33% + flyspell-post-command-hook
11,394,237  27% + corfu--post-command
8,081,767  19% + command-execute
8,069,640  19% + redisplay_internal (C function)

CPU

Samples % Function
1032  27% + flyspell-post-command-hook
740  19% + corfu--post-command
676  17% + redisplay_internal (C function)
653  17% + ...

My config for Flyspell and Corfu is
;; Corfu
(use-package corfu
  :custom
  (corfu-auto t)
  (corfu-auto-prefix 1)
  (corfu-auto-delay 0.1)
  :init
  (global-corfu-mode)
  (corfu-history-mode))

;;Flyspell
(add-hook 'flyspell-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq flyspell-issue-message-flag nil)
        (flyspell-buffer)))


How can I address this bottleneck? I've tried narrowing the buffer, but it seems to change nothing.

I would turn off flyspell and see how much that improves things, then turn off corfu, then turn both of them off. If any of these alternatives provides acceptable performance, I would send bug reports to the respective project(s).

@NickD Thank you. It appears that the issue is actually font lock. Do you suggest that I close this question?

No, I think it's a useful question.

Turned off both Flyspell and Corfu (as suggested by NickD) revealed that font-lock was the problem. Simply turning it off was a good temporary fix.
Further digging found that it was specific to Markdown Mode and only in areas with lots of links. There are several GitHub issues for this. However, a fix was merged recently. Updating to the MELPA version of Markdown Mode gave me this fix, thus removing the problem. Notably, reducing font-lock-maximum-decoration did not help.
